# Proof of additivity/linearity of expectations

Tags: probability-theory

(1) Suppose $\mathbb{E}[X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]$ holds for any random variables $X\geq 0,Y\geq 0$.

(2) The expectation of a general random variable $X$ is defined as $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^+]-\mathbb{E}[X^-]$.

How do I prove $\mathbb{E}[X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]$ for general random variables $X,Y$? That is, how to extend the additivity of expectation for non-negative random variables to the case of general random variables? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
(X+Y)^+ + X^- + Y^-=(X+Y)^- + X^+ + Y^+,
$$
$$
\mathsf{E}(X+Y)^+ +\mathsf{E}X^- +\mathsf{E}Y^-=\mathsf{E}(X+Y)^- +\mathsf{E}X^+ +\mathsf{E}Y^+
$$
by (1). Thus, assuming that all terms are finite,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}(X+Y) &=\mathsf{E}(X+Y)^+ - \mathsf{E}(X+Y)^- \\
&=(\mathsf{E}X^+ -\mathsf{E}X^-) +(\mathsf{E}Y^+ - \mathsf{E}Y^-) \\
&=\mathsf{E}X + \mathsf{E}Y.
\end{align}